# Unable to import the routing in symfony

Tags: symfony

I am using the Jobeet tutorial.

I have configured the routing in app/confing file as follow:

```
EnsJobeetBundle:
    resource: "@EnsJobeetBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

In EnsJobeetBundle routing it is defined as below:

```
EnsJobeetBundle_job:
    resource: "@EnsJobeetBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml"
    prefix: /job
```

When I am using the URL `http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/job/` I get the following error:

```
Cannot import resource "@EnsJobeetBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml" 
 from "C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\Ens\JobeetBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml". 
Make sure the "EnsJobeetBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml" bundle 
 is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.
```

I have also registerd in appkernel file also as follow:

```
new Ens\JobeetBundle\EnsJobeetBundle(),
```

What may cause these errors?

Comment: Please, paste the contents of your `job.yml`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when trying a production url I was getting this same error.

In app/AppKernel.php there is a condition that only considers 'dev' and 'test' environment:

```
   if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test')))
```

if your bundle should also be enabled in prod environment you should modify the condition:

```
   if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('prod', 'dev', 'test')))
```

This solved the error for me.